# View controller not taking up entire window frame in Mac OSX project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, uiviewcontroller, window

So I'm creating a mac OSX app and right now I have a main view controller set up to be the size of the window and a NSView subview on top of the view controller with the same frame size. However, this is the result I am getting: (I colored the NSView subview pinkish)

[image]

**What I want is for the whole window to be taken up by the NSView subview (so the whole window should be pink).** Here is my code thus far:

In AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    self.mainViewController = [[NSViewController alloc]
                           initWithNibName:Nil bundle:Nil];
    self.mainViewController.view.frame = ((NSView *)self.window.contentView).bounds;
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.mainViewController.view];

}
```

And then in my view controller:

```
-(void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    NSView *myView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    CALayer *viewLayer = [CALayer layer];
    [viewLayer setBackgroundColor:CGColorCreateGenericRGB(100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4)];
    [myView setWantsLayer:YES]; 
    [myView setLayer:viewLayer];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];  
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your description doesn't make sense. View Controllers don't have a size and aren't visible. A view controller is simply code that coordinates the view and the model. The view should be the entirety of the visible portion.

Comment: The view controller comes with a built in view...and it's the view controllers view frame that is off...

Comment: the view controllers view doesn't have a size

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a subview to your `view controller` in your `loadView:` method, you should set the view of `view controller` here as:

```
-(void)loadView
{
     .
     .
     .

    // [self.view addSubview:myView];    //update this to

    [self setView: myView];
}
```